# Swift 4 - expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9, swift4

I'm getting an error that this expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time on swift 4
Can anyone help me?

```
- AppDelegate.removeGIF(withURL: "images/" + self.currentUID + "/" + self.thisPostId + "." + self.currentGifExt)
```

Comment: Use string interpolation instead of concatenation  `"images/\(self.currentUID)/\(self.thisPostId).\(self.currentGifExt)"`

Answer (score 5):

Using operators are by far the most difficult thing for your compiler to type check

Try using string interpolation

```
AppDelegate.removeGIF(withURL: "images/\(self.currentUID)/\(self.thisPostId).\(self.currentGifExt)")
```

Alternatively you can just tell the compiler the type so it won’t even have to typecheck.

```
let urlStr: String = "images/" + self.currentUID + "/" + self.thisPostId + "." + self.currentGifExt
AppDelegate.removeGIF(withURL: urlStr)
```